# using php in JS file

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to use JS to direct a user to their profile page on login. I need to get the profile id in the url but it's not working.

```
            if(data == 'success'){
                window.location = 'profile.php?id=<?= $user_id ?>';
            } else {
                $('#signin_errors').html(data);
            }
```

Any advice?

Comment: Do you have short php tags turned on from php.ini? or use full php tags.

Comment: Do you have [short_tags enabled](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php)?

Comment: As the answers have stated, make sure this is in a PHP file (or a file you set up to be processed with PHP).

Comment: you can store the value of $user_id in js variable and append it with others.  But i will recommend to use php directly instead of using the js variable.

Comment: thanks for the answers. i don't have short tags enabled, it seems that the best option is the answer rickyduck and a few others mentioned below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a file included in `<script src="blah.js"></script>` change it to `<script src="blah.php"></script>` and stick this code in `blah.php`

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
$user_id = "whatever"; ?>

if(data == 'success'){
   window.location = 'profile.php?id=<?php echo $user_id ?>';
} else {
   $('#signin_errors').html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to print or echo the variable.

```
if(data == 'success'){
    window.location = 'profile.php?id=<?php print $user_id; ?>';
} 
else {
    $('#signin_errors').html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line into your .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .js
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add php in your javascript file because your server will not recognize it unless you add it to your httpd.conf

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .js
```

Comment: I recommend not to do that. Doing that will create too much work on the server. It's best to use the js code in a .php file and work accordingly

Comment: I was just explaining how PHP works. I don't know his specific situation.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can directly putting this to a **PHP file** it'll work. For example:

```
<?php
echo "blablabla";
?>
<script>
if(data == 'success'){
                window.location = 'profile.php?id=<?= $user_id ?>';
            } else {
                $('#signin_errors').html(data);
            }

</script>
```

But if you put this to a **.js file**, it won't work ! Because it's not a PHP FILE, it's a JS FILE. Apache won't read php codes inside of JS file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to do this inside a php file and echo the script you want there. Be sure to escape the required char's.

Something like:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    myjavascriptcode();
$('mybutton').set('html', '<input id=\"mybutton\" type=\"submit\" value=\"" . $php_variable . "\" />');
}); 
</script>";
```